# Which pre-2000 set had a mobile crane with lights?

Tags: sets, 9v

I had a set similar to this when I was younger (I am fairly sure this was before the year 2000), although:

- The model was red, rather than yellow.
- The model was more of a breakdown truck, rather than a cargo lorry.
- The model used a cleveryly hidden 9V battery to power a winch and flashing lights.
- There were no supporting "arms" coming out the side like in the model below.

Can anybody help me find what set it was?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the set you're looking for is the [F1 Hauler (item no. 6484-1)](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=6484-1):

[image]

Here are the details:

- It was released in 1995.
- It's a red-and-white truck for towing Formula 1 cars (and has no support legs).
- It has an [8 x 4 x 2.33 9V battery box](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=4760c01), which is hidden in the body of the 6-stud-wide truck.
- It has a [1 x 4 light bar](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=4771) and a motorized winch driven by a [9V micromotor](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=2986).

[image]

Comment: That's it! Although I do not remember the the battery box being the tool chest, I thought it was built into the model and hidden behind the panels. After reading the reviews I see the model is 6 studs wide and the battery box was 4, so it's certainly possible. I'll have to see if I can find the manual somehwere.

Comment: @tombull89: You're right about the battery box. The first image I found made it hard to tell what the width of the truck was. I'll update with a better picture.

Comment: I found my copy of the manual and took a picture of stage 14 which shows the location of the battery box.